# Email sent out from server is just me@servername, not me@domain.com

Tags: postfix

I'm successfully sending out email from a server using Postfix smtpd, but on the receiving end, the emails are just coming from dan@emerson (emerson is the name of the originating host), and not dan@mydomain.com. Thus they get put in spam. In `main.cf` I've set `mydomain` and `myorigin` to "mydomain.com" (the real domain withheld). Is there anything else I should check so I can get the outgoing emails to be sent from dan@mydomain.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
echo "Message body" | mail -s "Some subject" -r dan@mydomain.com  destination@receiver.com
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I wonder why I don't need to use the `-r` option with `mail` when I do the same from a different Ubuntu server, which *does* put the domain name after the user name.

Comment: @dan A message is built of of fields - one field is typically the "From:" field, which you can use to specify what "From" address to send from.  This is typically used to specify where emails are 'from' from the same server, so unless you specify the "From" field, it doesn't work very well and will default to `user@machinehostname` (rather than the `myhostname` settings).  This way, one mail server can reply for multiple domains.

Comment: @ThomasW. Is it usual to have to use the `-r [fromemail@domain.com]` flag when using `mail` to send email out of the local network? I hadn't thought that was the case.

Comment: @dan given my entire backend of how I test my mail server is done via Python, I don't typically test things like this.  However, it's NOT uncommon to have to specify the origin address (i.e. the From address) in messages originating on the local network, when going outbound.  It's actually *RFC Dictated* that you should have a `From:` field populated when sending a message, so unless it's specified, it's usually `user@hostname` gathered from the currently logged in session.